# Cannot bind mysql data to html template in golang

Tags: mysql, go

UPDATE: There is no error from anywhere whatsoever! In the browser, there is no error in the console or network tab. In the terminal running the go code, there is no error either. All errors in go are logged; for brevity I removed the error handling in the question.

Trying to follow a book about writing web app using Go.
I have a local mysql db which I can get data from using `database/sql` package. I am parsing the template using `html/template` package but somehow can't bind the data into the template.

This is the model:

```
type Snippet struct {
    ID      int
    Title   string
    Content string
    Created time.Time
    Expires time.Time
}
```

This is the `handler` for showing the data (error handling is omitted):

```
func (app *application) showSnippet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.URL.Query().Get("id"))
    s, _ := app.snippets.Get(id) // get data from database!
    files := []string{
        "./ui/html/show.page.tmpl", // this is the template.
        "./ui/html/base.layout.tmpl",
        "./ui/html/footer.partial.tmpl", // either relative or absolute path!
    }
    ts, _ := template.ParseFiles(files...)
    _ = ts.Execute(w, s) // write the template set content as the response body; 
    
    // NOTE: this does print out data fine so data is indeed retrieved from the db.
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n%s", s.Title, s.Content) 
}
```

Here is the `show.page.tmpl` template:

```
{{template "base" .}}
{{define "title"}}Snippet #{{.ID}}{{end}}
{{define "main"}}
<div class='snippet'>
    <div class='metadata'>
        <strong>{{.Title}}</strong>
        <span>#{{.ID}}</span>
    </div>
    <pre><code>{{.Content}}</code></pre>
    <div class='metadata'>
        <time>Created: {{.Created}}</time>
        <time>Expires: {{.Expires}}</time>
    </div>
</div>
{{end}}
```

On the page, it doesn't display the data as it's empty; but the debug line is printed fine at the bottom.
What went wrong?

[image]

Comment: @CeriseLimón In the question the error handling is omitted for brevity; in practice the error from `ts.Execute(w, s)` is logged using a centralized error handling.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Sorry but there is no error from anywhere. In the browser, there is no error, in the terminal, there is no error. I just don't see any error at all. As you see, the debug message is printed on the last line, if there is any error before that, it would have been displayed somewhere.

Comment: See [this example](https://go.dev/play/p/juoHRBZJ_tZ).  The template works in isolation.  Post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to compile the templates in the HTTP handler (basically in every request)

Assuming you created the files with the template names and an `.htm` extension, you can do something like this (or even add them to the application struct)

```
// Define a global templates variable (or add it to the application if you want)
var templates *template.Template
// For compiling the templates
// in a subdirectory called "templates" with files ending in .htm
func getTemplates() (templates *template.Template, err error) {
    var allFiles []string
    templateDir := "templates"
    files2, _ := ioutil.ReadDir(templateDir)
    for _, file := range files2 {
        filename := file.Name()
        if strings.HasSuffix(filename, ".htm") {
            filePath := filepath.Join(templateDir, filename)
            allFiles = append(allFiles, filePath)
        }
    }
    templates, err = template.New("").ParseFiles(allFiles...)
    LogPanic(err, "Error building templates")
    return
}
// load them on init
func init() {
    var err error
    templates, err = getTemplates()
    if err != nil {
        log.Panicf("%s: %s \n", "ERROR compiling templates", err)
    }
}
```

Now that you have the templates compiled, you can execute them in the HTTP handler, and log the error if there's any (please share if you see any errors as Cerise Limón suggested) remember to update the template name in the code.

```
func (app *application) showSnippet(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    id, _ := strconv.Atoi(r.URL.Query().Get("id"))
    s, _ := app.snippets.Get(id)
    err := templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "template_name", s)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("%s: %s \n", "ERROR executing template", err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "%s\n%s", s.Title, s.Content) 
}
```